# Automate web using excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to automate this website: "checkcosmetic.net" using excel vba.
What I have done so far is:

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim frm As Object
Dim htm As HTMLDocument
____________________________________________________

Sub checkNow()
ie.navigate ("www.checkcosmetic.net")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Silent = True
Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set htm = ie.document
Set frm = htm.forms.Item

For Each elm In frm
'
'how to select "brands?"
'
If elm.ID = "codeinput" Then
elm.Value = "09076JU40" 'LOT No. of a Vaseline body moisturizing cream
End If

If elm.ID = "codesubmit" Then
elm.Click 'not triggering?
End If
Next elm
End Sub
```

What I am unable to do is to select the options list programmtically.

My objective is to check the expiration date of the cosmetics from Excel.

For example:

   product: "Vaseline", Lot No.: "09076JU40"=> "7 of September, 2016"

Comment: This code will never allow you to edit the Data in Excel. Since you are navigating the site not the sheet,, !!

Comment: I know. I have hard coded the “data source”

Comment: I think you are confused !! One method I can suggest provide Link of the Excel file on Web Page to edit.

Comment: I am not confused. If someone could help me change the “options list” via code, I can do the rest...I mean I can connect to the Excel data on my own. Thank you. (I did that for the shake of simplicity)